# Find the value of $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ given the following conditions without using CS inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

We are asked to solve for the value of $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ given that

$$ f(1) = 0 \tag{1}  $$  $$ \\ \int_{0}^{1}[f'(x)]^2dx = 7 \tag{2} \\ $$ $$ \int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)dx = \frac{1}{3} \tag{3} $$

We can solve this using Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality:

From $(3)$ we can use integration by parts to obtain

$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^3f'(x)dx = -1 \tag{4}$$

With $(2)$ and $(3)$, and from Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

$$ \Big[ \int_{0}^{1}x^3f'(x)dx \Big]^2 \leq \underbrace{\Big( \int_{0}^{1}[x^3]^2dx \Big)}_{\frac{1}{7}} \underbrace{\Big( \int_{0}^{1}[f'(x)]^2dx\Big)}_{7 \text{ from } (2)}$$

Therefore we have,

$$ 1 \leq 1 $$

Thus an equality, which in turn implies $f'(x) = ax^3$ where $a$ is just a scalar.

From $(1)$ we have,

$$f(x) = \frac{a}{4}x^4 + C \rightarrow f(1) = \frac{a}{4} + C  = 0 $$

and from $(2)$ we have,

$$ \int_{0}^{1}[f'(x)]^2dx = \int_{0}^{1}(ax^3)^2dx = a^2\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x^6dx}_{\frac{1}{7}} = 7 \rightarrow a = \pm 7$$

$$f(x) = \pm \frac{7}{4}x^4 \mp \frac{7}{4}$$

and finally from $(3)$ we can see

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^2\big(-\frac{7}{4}x^4 +\frac{7}{4} \big) dx = \frac{1}{3} $$

but

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^2\big(\frac{7}{4}x^4 - \frac{7}{4} \big) dx = - \frac{1}{3} $$

Therefore we can conclude

$$ \boxed{f(x) = -\frac{7}{4}x^4 +\frac{7}{4}} $$

and

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}-\frac{7}{4}x^4 +\frac{7}{4}dx = \frac{7}{5}}$$

This concludes the solution using CS inequality. But are there other methods to solve this, preferably only using high-school/AP level calculus?

Comment: The specific question here is : which method , if any, can help students know what to make of $\int [f'(x)]^2 dx$? That quantity so fundamentally screams "Cauchy-Schwarz", but I don't recall anything about it being discussed before CS. Any high school method must know what high schoolers think about that particular term. The only other hint I can give is that typically minimizers tend to be polynomials, so one can interpret this as a linear algebra problem if the derivatives are restricted over polynomials (i.e. finite dimensional spaces).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer from the vague memories i have from physics undergrad, i recalled some quantities involving the integration of $(\nabla \phi)^2$ and we used product rules to get there. So I was thinking about using product rule of maybe $(f(x) f'(x))'$ and some algebra could get us somewhere, but I got lost.

Comment: @VladeKR $f’(x)^2$ appears in $(f(x)f’(x))’=f(x)f’’(x)+(f(x))^2$. But you’d have to introduce $f(x)f’’(x)$ which makes it messy.

Comment: @insipidintegrator yes that's very true, but my calculus is very rusty so I came here looking for some insights.

Comment: I'm not able to work around Cauchy-Schwarz. A *heuristic* (i.e. non-rigorous) argument centering around *uniqueness* will tell you if $f$ is a polynomial then $f$ has degree $4$. However, nothing I've done makes rigorous sense (and I'm not able to make sense of it) , so I'll avoid writing an answer here.

Comment: You can use $ab\le {7\over 2}a^2+{1\over 14}b^2$ with $a=x^3$ and $b=f'$ The equality holds if $b=7a.$